# Как сделать сайт авторизации?Помогите

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть страница[image: Эта страница] И я не могу понять как сделать так чтобы когда ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ логин и пароль,переходил на другую страницу.А когда не правильный выводил "НЕВЕРНО"
Я НАЧИНАЮЩИЙ ПРОГРАММИСТ,ПОМОГИТЕ МНЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.

Comment: Вы слышали о фронтенде и бекенде? Если нет то вот почитайте для начала википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_и_back_end короче говоря для проверки пароля и логина вам нужен сервер который будет отвечать за логику, например сервер Apache + php + mysql или Node.js + mongodb. Вариантов очень много.

Comment: читайте о PHP, SQL и прочем. Или посмотрите в сторону готовых движков. На крайний случай, есть такое уг как uCoz.